# Iterating through a Dictionary passed as a parameter in a function in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I tried iterating through a dictionary I passed as a function parameter got and got the error:

Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

```swift
func test (body: Dictionary<String, String>? = nil) {
        for (key,value) in body {
            print(key,"key")
            print(value,"value")
        }
}
```

Subsequently, I modified the code to:

```swift
typealias dict = [String:String]
func test (body: dict? = [:]) {
        for (key,value) in body {
            print(key,"key")
            print(value,"value")
        }
}
```

I'm performing the call like so;

```swift
test(body: ["name":"Sidney"])
```

And my expected result should be:

```swift
key name
value Sidney
```

Comment: `for let (key, value) in body`

Comment: Thank You Fogmeister !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an optional body that can't be directly iterated.
You must first unwrap it and after you can do what you want.

```
func test (body: dict? = [:]) {
    if let body {
        for (key,value) in body {
            print(key,"key")
            print(value,"value")
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can just replace the optional with an empty dictionary.

```
typealias dict = [String:String]
func test (body: dict = [:]) {
    for (key,value) in body {
        print(key,"key")
        print(value,"value")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A much more modern, Swifty way of doing this would be to do it this way...

```
func test(body: [String: String]? = nil) {
  body?.forEach { (key, value) in // the ? will only perform the forEach if body is not nil
    print(key,"key")
    print(value,"value")
  }
}
```